# Hosting a silverlight 3 business application in IIS 7 app pool

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, web-config, shared-hosting

I have a silverlight 3 business application. It is running fine in my local IIS6. 
But now I want to host this app through an ISP where they have IIS7 or higher. 
After deploying the application I am getting a HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error.

the detailed error information is as follows:

**Module IIS Web Core

Notification Unknown

Handler Not yet determined

Error Code 0x800700b7

Config Error There is a duplicate system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler section defined
Config File \?\C:\ClientSites\eda-cloud.com\httpdocs\web.config

Requested URL /

Physical Path

Logon Method Not yet determined 
Logon User Not yet determined**

Config Source

```
5:<sectionGroup name="scripting"        type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup,
System.Web.Extensions,
Version=3.5.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">

6:<section name="scriptResourceHandler"
type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection,   System.Web.Extensions, 
Version=3.5.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
requirePermission="false" 
allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>

7:<sectionGroup name="webServices"  type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup,    System.Web.Extensions, 
Version=3.5.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

I have searched the web for this error, lots of information is there for this issue. like http://bradkingsley.com/resolving-a-there-is-a-duplicate-system-web-extensionsscriptingscriptresourcehandler-section-defined-error/ or http://forums.iis.net/t/1149226.aspx

I am a bit confused of exactly what to do. I have changed the Version of these three sections from 3.5.0.0 to 4.0.0.0, but the same error still remains.
Should I remove these blocks from my config file altogether? Please help me.